# Java UI designer for end-user

Tags: java, javascript, swing, user-interface

I'm making a [Java Swing application](https://symatapp.com) where the user can run and edit JavaScript and Python code using a ScriptEngine.  I want the user to be able to drag-and-drop design custom frames with standard components (buttons, text boxes, etc) and specify code to run when buttons are pressed or text is typed.  I will also need a way to load and save the forms and run them inside my app.  Are there any libraries I can use for this?  I've tried searching around but I'm not finding much.

Comment: Just to confirm you want a lib for Java that will allow for the dragging of buttons etc not for java script right?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato Yes.  My application allows scripts to be run with JavaScript, I want the scripts to be accessible from user-designed Java UIs.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @bigdestroyer Netbeans, why?

Comment: Normally, each IDE has its own swing UI designer. In Eclipse you can isntall WindowBuilder, in IntelliJ there is one by default. I suppose there is another one for Netbeans.

Comment: @bigdestroyer My users won't be using Netbeans, they will be using my application.  And FYI, Netbeans has a built-in designer.